# Unable to get desired result in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm using this code to do something -

```
// Initialize variables
double x;
...
// Here is where I'm facing problem
while (cin >> x){
    if (x == '|'){
        cout << "\nBreaking the loop\n"; // Edit1: Unable to produce output
        break;
    }
   // Do something
     ...
}

// Do some other things
cout << "\nAfter the loop";       // Edit1: This gets executed,
cin >> x;                         //        but this doesn't.
...
// End
```

But, when I enter `'|'`, the window closes without even outputting this - `Breaking the loop` and doesn't execute the statements after the while loop (I think).

I'm using Visual C++.

Why is this happening? Is there any solution to it?

Comment: it breaks the look because cin >> x evaluates to false as '|' can't be initialized to a double.

Comment: `|` is not a valid character in a textual representation of a `double` value. Therefore, `cin >> x` sets `cin.failbit()` when it encounters this character in the input stream. This causes the loop condition to become `false`.

Comment: Try `cout << "\nBreaking the loop" << endl;`

Comment: @IvanWalulya: But even if I use `int`, instead of `double`, it produces the output `Breaking the loop`, but still the window closes again, and it does not execute any code after while loop.

Comment: [Can't reproduce](http://rextester.com/GUXNBN24745). [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or it didn't happen.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: When I run the same code here on Visual C++, it just shows that `After the loop` output directly without outputting `Breaking the loop`, and closes the window. I'm trying to read a new value into x after the while loop, but it isn't happening.

Comment: Once `failbit` is set on a stream, it will remain set. You can reset it with `cin.clear()`. Further, the `|` character was never extracted from the input stream - if you try to read a `double` again, the first character read would be `|`, and it would fail again the same way as the first time. You can use `cin.ignore()` to skip some characters.

Answer (score 0):

Change to using a char instead of double

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
 {
 char x;
 // Here is where I'm facing problem
 while (cin >> x){
    if (x == '|'){
        cout << "\nBreaking the loop\n";
        break;
    }
   // Do something
 }

 }
```

Comment: But for other cases, I always have to read `x` as `double`. This is piece of code is only for exiting the loop.

Comment: If u need a character exit sequence, then you gonna have to use a cin >> string and then use atof to convert to double. But clearly the implicit conversion aint happening.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you.